# Upload to webserver from multiple devices

Tags: ios6

Ive developed an app which needs to upload a small .xml file to a web server, there will be around 15 devices running this app uploading around 15 .xml files each per day. The files need to be uploaded to the same directory.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Im assuming i cant use the same login details for the server on every device, is there any hosting out there that allows multiple different logins?

Thanks.
Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Parse.com's](https://www.parse.com) data solution.  You can set up a free account and have your devices post the data a database using their API.  Pretty easy to set up with iOS and for basic services it's free.

Comment: Thank you, ill take a look into it. How reliable is parse.com?

Comment: I've used it successfully in my iOS app and it's Rails back end with no issues for the past 6 months or so.  Development was a snap using their library.  You also get a nice web GUI to view, search, and edit the data.

Comment: Just looking through the documentation now, i think this will save me bundles of time and effort. Thanks a lot.